# Open up Facebook Request Dialog using a username as parameter

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to open up the request dialog using a specific username. I can see at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests#scenarios) that there's such a option, but do not know how to use it.

I'm doing something like the following while calling requestDialog("Test Message", "Adam Scot")

```
function requestDialog(message,to) {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
              message: message,
              to: to
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
```

However I'm getting an error: "Adam Scot is not a valid user id".
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use usernames in any way anymore. You can´t even get them after authorizing the user anymore. The "to" parameter only accepts an ID. Btw, "Adam Scot" is not the username, it´s the name of the user. Yes, there is a difference :) - And it´s not possible to use that one either, you MUST use an ID.

You get the ID from authorizing a user with basic permission, but i assume you can use [`invitable_friends`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.4) too, and use the invite token you get from that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Scot is a user name, not a user ID.

Comment: Please read again my question. I want to open up the request dialog using a user name as parameter, not id.